# How does one transfer data from an iPhone 6 to a Pixel 6 pro that has already been set up (without a reset)?

Tags: data-transfer, ios

So this is not the first time I turn on my Pixel 6 pro. When I connect the devices with a cable (this [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071G6NLHJ/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071G6NLHJ))  no options appear so it is unclear what to do next to transfer the data and the video I was watching doesn't suggest what to actually do:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1IPSE2avCE

and I've tried a bunch of things like google one etc but the contacts and the videos from my iphone 6 s are NOT on my pixel.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

---

this never happens (https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7129740?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccopy-data-from-your-old-phone-with-a-cable-recommended):

> When asked to “Copy Apps & Data,” tap Next and then Copy your data.

---

I also tried google one but I don't see my contacts or videos form my iphone on my pixel. Why?

Comment: cross: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-does-one-transfer-data-from-an-iPhone-6-to-a-Pixel-6-Pro-that-has-already-been-set-up and https://www.reddit.com/r/Pixel6/comments/vv5xwv/how_does_one_transfer_data_from_an_iphone_6_to_a/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/443591/how-does-one-transfer-data-from-an-iphone-6-to-a-pixel-6-pro-that-has-already-be

Comment: perhaps this will do it? the first option? the second one seems more work? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEdVU96bol8

Comment: cross to pixel reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Pixel6/comments/vv6roi/how_does_one_transfer_data_from_an_iphone_6_to_a/

Answer (score 0):

honestly the main take away is to do it once during setup of the phone.

Will post it as a community answer since I'm not too happy that I had to download a third party app and that it doesn't seem to be using the cables I bought...I used the `Send Anywhere (File Transfer) app`. Instructions in video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEdVU96bol8 in text:

1. download `Send Anywhere (File Transfer) app`
2. choose the videos, photos, contacts etc from the iphone
3. choose the pixel to be a receiver
4. get the code from the iphone put it in the receiver
   then click send

done...or at least I hope the transfer happens. Going on right now.